# API Gateway direct request to AWS Batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

In the API Gateway UI for Integration Requests, it lets you select AWS Service --> Batch.

How can I create Batch Jobs pointed to a Batch Job Definition (via ARN?) from here?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

@Kalanos, I have captured the full details in [this blog post](http://it20.info/2021/11/submitting-an-aws-batch-job-from-aws-api-gateway/) but here it is the TL/DR in case:

Integration request configuration:

```
Integration Type: AWS Service
AWS Region: us-east-2
AWS Service: Batch
HTTP method: POST
Action Type: Use path override
    Path override: /v1/submitjob
```

Mapping Template:

```
application/json:
{
  "jobName": "arbitrary-job-name",
  "jobQueue": "[job-queue-name]",
  "jobDefinition": "[job-definition-name]"
}
```

Note that the `jobQueue` and `jobDefinition` need to be pre-configured in AWS Batch. The `Execution role` needs to be an IAM role that have a trust with the `API GW service` and have enough permissions to submit a job to Batch.